# Exceptions for building extrusions

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm creating a Mapbox scene with three.js. I have 3D models of some buildings which are rendered with custom layer and three.js. For the remaining buildings, I want to extrude the buildings basically in the same way as the example in the docs shows (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/). Can I specify that the extrusion should not happen for the modeled buildings?

The current situation looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGMGI.jpg

I read that you can use polygons to specify a certain region for a layer, but I'm not sure if it works the same way with the extruded buildings.

Is this even possible with the current state? Has anybody already faced a similar problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to see if the Mapbox Streets buildings layer have IDs. If so you can exclude those buildings by ID.